# How prevent double rendering in react based on asynchronous call in componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, call, mount

I've a parent component and two child component. One success and one failure
I need to show these component based on an asynchronous call when page loads. 
So I did the asynchronous call on page componentDidMount. But this is causing double rendering.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    showSuccessPage: false
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  ActiveAccount.fetchActiveAccount(this.handleSuccess, this.handleFailure)
}

handleSuccess() {
  this.setState({
    showSuccessPage: true
  )}
}

...

render() {
  ...
  return (
    {showSuccessPage && <SuccessPage />}
    {!showSuccessPage && <FailurePage />}
  )
}
```

It always render the failurePage first and then update to render successPage. how can I prevent double rendering?

Comment: You can shorten your render logic to `showSuccessPage ? <SuccessPage /> : <FailurePage />`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to render components as intended, a binary state is not enough. This can be expressed with single state property `showSuccessPage` that has 3 values, `undefined`, `true` and `false`. Or with 2 state properties:

```
  ...
  {state.accountFetched && (
    state.accountFetchSuccess ? <SuccessPage/> : <FailurePage/>
  )}
  ...
```